# How to wait until the NSTimer stops

Tags: objective-c++

I have a method that returns a string value. 
In that method, I have two calls to other methods. The first one contains a NSTimer. The other contains a distributed notification.
The previous methods modify the string variable that returns the main method (bgp_result).
I need to wait for the method that contains my NSTimer to finish in order to continue with the execution to return the correct value in my main method.
All the methods are in the same class as well as the variable "bgp_result".

Here is my objective-c++ code.

```
std::string MyProjectAPI::bgp(const std::string& val)
{       
    FBTest *test = [[FBTest alloc] init];
    NSString *parameters_objc = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:val.c_str()];
    test.parameter_val = parameters_objc;

    // This are the two methods 
    //This method runs the NSTimer. I need to "stop" the execution of the main code until the method launchTimerToCatchResponse finish in order to get an updated value in the variable "bgp_result".
    [test launchTimerToCatchResponse]; 

    [test sendPluginConfirmationNotification];

    const char *bgp_res = [test.bgp_result cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [test release];

    return bgp_res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s usually best when you can rewrite the function using an asynchronous handler, so that the caller can decide if he wants to wait or if he’s happy processing the results asynchronously, too:

```
typedef void (^BGPConsumer)(NSString *bgpInfo);

- (void) fetchBGPData: (BGPConsumer) consumer
{
    …
    [self scheduleTimerThatEventuallyCalls:^{
        NSString *info = [self nowWeHaveBGPInfo];
        consumer(info);
    }];
    …
}
```

If that’s not an option, you can block the execution using a semaphore:

```
- (void) timesUp
{
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(timerSemaphore);
}

- (void) launchTimerToCatchResponse
{
    [self setTimerSemaphore:dispatch_semaphore_create(0)];
    // …schedule a timer that calls -timesUp after some time
}

- (void) blockedMethod
{
    …
    [self launchTimerToCatchResponse];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(timerSemaphore);
    dispatch_release(timerSemaphore);
    [self setTimerSemaphore:nil];
    …
}
```